# How to properly format the data I am getting from an API call

Tags: javascript, get, axios

I come to you all as a last resort. So essentially I am building the inner workings for a jeopardy game using the [jService API](http://jservice.io/). So essentially I was tasked with making an API call to `/api/random` and to gather 100 category ID's into an array. That's fine, no problem.

```js
let categories = [];
let categoryIDs = [];

async function getCategoryIds() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://jservice.io//api/categories?count=100');
    console.log(res.data)
    for (let cat of res.data) {
        categoryIDs.push(cat.id)
    }
    console.log(categoryIDs)
}
```

Returns exactly what I need it to. Where I am struggling is with the second part. Now for every category ID I am suppose to return a list of questions and answers as follows:

```js
//  [
//    { title: "Math",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "2+2", answer: 4, showing: null},
//        {question: "1+1", answer: 2, showing: null}
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    { title: "Literature",
//      clues: [
//        {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
//        {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
//        ...
//      ],
//    },
//    ...
//  ]
```

And here is what I have written so far:

```js
async function getCategory(categoryIDs) {
    const res2 = await axios.get("http://jservice.io/api/clues", {
        params: {
          category: 11603
        }
      });
    console.log(res2.data)
    console.log(res2.data[0].category.title + ':', res2.data[0].question, res2.data[0].answer)
    console.log(res2.data[1].category.title + ':', res2.data[1].question, res2.data[1].answer)
    console.log(res2.data[2].category.title + ':', res2.data[2].question, res2.data[2].answer)
    console.log(res2.data[3].category.title + ':', res2.data[3].question, res2.data[3].answer)
    console.log(res2.data[4].category.title + ':', res2.data[4].question, res2.data[4].answer)
}
```

And I realize that all of the `console.log` are not giving me the data formatted how I need it formatted, I was simply trying to assess whether or not I could actually pull the data and play with it.

I am not in school, and this is not homework, nor am I really looking for answers, just clarity. I have two questions: 1) with just one function call, `async function getCategory(categoryIDs)` what is the best way, or the correct way to pass in 100 separate category ID's to my query parameter so that it will return an array of information on all categories? And what is the best way to get my data structured like in the example above.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the `categoryIds` an array of strings that match the `title` property of the array of objects that comes next?

Comment: No, categoryIds is an array of numbers that represent a category. For example, you could have 111582 which represents the 'Math' category @IraklisGkougkousis

Comment: Do you have the connection categoryId <---> categoryName stored somewhere? It would help if you edited your question and included some example values for all your variables, and what you expect to get from each get request. I'm kind of lost at the moment

Comment: Of course, thank you for the critique, I will jump on that now! @IraklisGkougkousis